# How to Get value from session on Oninit in angular8?

Tags: typescript, angular8, session-storage

I am Storing access token on session storage during the time of login and accessing it on other components oninit() method but getting null value.
checked on the console it stores token on session .

Here is set session storage on post httpclient request

```
.subscribe(
    (data: any) => { // json data

      console.log('Success: ', data);
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token ",data.access_token)
        this._router.navigate( ['dashboard'] );

  },
```

and here i am accessing this token on other component

```
ngOnInit() {
    let url:string = '.......';
     const token  = sessionStorage.getItem("Token");
     console.log(token);


    this.http.get(url,
    {
      headers : new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization' :'Bearer '+ token
      })
    }
    ).subscribe(
      (data: any)=> { // json data

       console.log('Success: ', data.data);
      this.leads = data.data;


   },
   error => {
       console.log('Error: ', error);
   }
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space at registering the Token.

```
      sessionStorage.setItem("Token ",data.access_token)
```

Remove the extra space after token and it should work.

Comment: ohhh shiitt i am such a dumb that was a silly mistake but thanks for your help it works

Answer (score 0):

Check using 
sessionStorage.setItem( Token, JSON.stringify(data.access_token) );

ans also 
JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem( Token ));

Answer (score 0):

```
  sessionStorage.setItem("Token ",data.access_token)// Typo. You have a space here after 'Token'

  sessionStorage.setItem("Token",data.access_token); // Removed space
```

If it still doesn't work then you should check whether the `Token` key setting is done before the `ngOnit` code where you are trying to retrieve it,